# Flex: Why are TileList images disappearing on drag?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, tilelist

I'm developing a Flex Air (desktop) application that loads images from the local filesystem into a TileList.  The user will then be able to drag (copy) these images out of the list onto another control.

I've finally got the images showing up correctly (and not disappearing after scrolling the TileList) but they seem to disappear from the TileList at the start of a drag operation.

I come from a .NET background and am just learning AS3/Flex, so if you see me using any anti-patterns here, feel free to point them out!

Sample code follows (I've tried to make this as minimal as possible).

**Test.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            protected var _pics:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            protected function picsList_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                const imageFolderPath:String = "c:\\users\\bbrooks\\Pictures";

                var imageDir:File = new File(imageFolderPath);
                var imageFiles:Array = imageDir.getDirectoryListing();
                for each(var imageFile:File in imageFiles)
                {
                    _pics.addItem(new PictureObject(imageFile.nativePath));
                }

                // give images a chance to load
                var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerExpired);
                timer.start();
            }

            protected function onTimerExpired(event:TimerEvent):void
            {
                picsList.dataProvider = _pics;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:TileList id="picsList" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="false"
                 creationComplete="picsList_creationCompleteHandler(event)" >
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <mx:Image width="75" height="75" source="{data.image}" />
            </fx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:TileList>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

**PictureObject.as:**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import mx.controls.Image;

    [Bindable]
    [RemoteClass]
    public class PictureObject extends Object
    {
        protected var _image:Image = null;
        public function get image():Image { return _image; }
        public function set image(newValue:Image):void { _image = newValue; }

        public function PictureObject(path:String)
        {
            var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
            imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));
        }

        protected function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var imageLoader:Loader = LoaderInfo(e.target).loader;
            var bmp:Bitmap = Bitmap(imageLoader.content);

            _image = new Image();           
            _image.smoothBitmapContent = true;
            _image.source = new Bitmap(bmp.bitmapData);
            _image.width = imageLoader.width;
            _image.height = imageLoader.height;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will mostly reply to your secondary question (guessing it will resolve the primary in one fell swoop): as anti-patterns go, this is not a bad example ;)

1. You are manually loading the images while the `Image` class has the loading built-in; just give a URL to its `source` property and it will automatically load it.
2. You are setting an `Image` instance as the source of another `Image` instance; the `source` property expects URLs or ByteArrays; I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error; the Image class is probably smart enough to extract the `source` of the other Image instance.
3. The `Timer` is redundant. As said, an `Image` automatically takes care of loading its content.
4. The `s:Image` tag isn't wrapped in an `ItemRenderer` and hence should have no access to a `data` property: this code shouldn't even compile.
5. There's no point in having a `Bindable` property `_pics` if you don't plan on binding it.
6. You use the mx TileList. Why not use the more "modern" Spark version? (This doesn't mean the mx class won't work in a Spark application though).

So you have a lot of deleting to do. You can scrap the PictureObject class altogether; remove the Timer code; and just add the URL Strings to the `_pics` collection. As a plus you could also replace the mx TileList with a Spark List with TileLayout; something like this:

```
<s:List id="picsList">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout />
    </s:layout>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:Image source="{data}" />
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

The ActionScript part could be reduced to this:

```
const imageFolderPath:String = "c:\\users\\bbrooks\\Pictures";

var imageDir:File = new File(imageFolderPath);
var imageFiles:Array = imageDir.getDirectoryListing();
picsList.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(imageFiles);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  To address your points... (1) I'm doing this to get around a problem I encountered where images would not redraw after the user scrolls the control forward and then back. (2) This was a mistake made in prepping this example.  I've updated the example source to more accurately reflect the original code.  (4) I'm using an mx:Image tag, and it is wrapped in an ItemRenderer.  (5) I was unaware that the s:List had a tile layout mode.  However, replacing the mx:TileList with the s:List results in the images not being drawn.

Comment: @BillBrooks (1) That should not be happening, so the problem must be somewhere else. Better track that down instead of trying to fix the symptoms. (4) My mistake: Flex does seem to automatically wrap it in an ItemRender with mx List. This will not work with a Spark List though: you'll have to do it explicitly then. (5) This could be because you didn't give it a width or height. For some reason it doesn't take a minimal size like a VerticalLayout would do. Or perhaps try setting `requestedColumnCount` or `requestedRowCount` on the TileLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks RIAstar.  Your answer put me on the track to solving the problem.  The new sample code appears below.

The original problem seems to have been with the mx:Image control.  Not sure why, but using the s:Image control seems to work.

Granted, this could be accomplished without the PictureObject class at all by simply setting the data source to a list of file paths, but I'm using the image data later and I wanted to get it working by supplying the image data to the custom renderer dynamically.

**Test.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.components.Image;

            protected var _pics:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            protected function picsList_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                const imageFolderPath:String = "c:\\users\\bbbrooks\\Pictures";

                var imageDir:File = new File(imageFolderPath);
                var imageFiles:Array = imageDir.getDirectoryListing();
                for each(var imageFile:File in imageFiles)
                {
                    if (imageFile.extension == "jpg")
                    {
                        _pics.addItem(new PictureObject(imageFile.nativePath));
                    }
                }

                // give images a chance to load
                var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerExpired);
                timer.start();
            }

            protected function onTimerExpired(event:TimerEvent):void
            {
                picsList.dataProvider = _pics;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="picsList" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" 
            creationComplete="picsList_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
            dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="false">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout />
        </s:layout>
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:ItemRenderer>
                    <s:Image id="imageDisplay" 
                             width="75" height="75" source="{data.bmp}" /> 
                </s:ItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

**PictureObject.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import mx.controls.Image;

    [RemoteClass]
    [Bindable]
    public class PictureObject extends Object
    {
        protected var _bmp:Bitmap = null;
        public function get bmp():Bitmap { return _bmp; }
        public function set bmp(newValue:Bitmap):void { _bmp = newValue; }

        public function PictureObject(path:String)
        {
            var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
            imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
            imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));
        }

        protected function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            var imageLoader:Loader = LoaderInfo(e.target).loader;

            // create our own copy of the bits in the Loader
            var bmp:Bitmap = Bitmap(imageLoader.content);
            _bmp = new Bitmap( Bitmap(imageLoader.content).bitmapData );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even in that case it's not really necessary: you can access the image data through [Image#bitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Image.html#bitmapData) (read-only)