# TileList scroll up or down, image lost

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

The first time, TileList works well. But when I scroll up or down, the `image` in the 
itemRenderer is lost(not show on the screen), but the `label` can still show.Following is the ItemRenderer in TileList:

```
<mx:VBox>
<script>
<![CDATA[
[Bindable]
private var url:String;

[Bindabl]
private var photoName:String;

override public function set data(value:Object):void {
     if(this.data == value) {
         return;
     }

     super.data = value;

     url = value.url;
     photoName = value.photoName;
  }
]]>
</script>
<mx:Image source="{url}"/>
<mx:Label text="{photoName}"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in mx:Image. I answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559213/flex-why-are-tilelist-images-disappearing-on-drag/10559438) last week. The problem disappeared when the OP used a s:Image instead. Since you tagged this question Flex3, I guess this won't be of much help, but at least you know.

Answer (score 0):

On your tile layout try configuring usevirtuallayout=false